# APF and iptables on router - disallow SSH on specific subnet host

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, linux-networking

I have a CentOS terminal working as a router with APF installed.

Also 1 terminal with 3 NICs (3 IPs) is using that router as a Gateway to access the internet.

What I want is APF to block SSH access, on the 2 of 3 NICs (IPs). So in result, SSH is only accessible for a specific IP and not all three.

How can I achieve that directly on the router with APF or iptables?

What I have tried: iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j DROP

Comment: What research have you done on this on your own - iptables examples and guides are not exactly difficult to find online, and the commands you'll need to run are quite simple.

Comment: I have tried: 
iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j DROP but it is not working .
I want to do this on the router than configuring port access to each subnet terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i <banned_interface> -d DESTINATION.IP -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i <banned_interface2> -d DESTINATION.IP -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

you could of course change the policy in the table to DROP by using iptables -P FORWARD DROP
and specify just the allowed entries but if you mess something up you'll be locked-out or forwarding would just not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 22 -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP
```

That did it. An easy one but I am new with iptables.